# Gmail API OAuth 2.0 - will my existing access token expires when I request for new access token?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

In my code I'm using refresh token to get new access token when my existing access token is about to expire within 15 mins. My question is, once I get the new access token can I still use old access token till it completely expires or will it expires immediately when I get the new access token?

Comment: I am pretty sure it will still work.  But why don't you just try it.

Comment: Access token expires in 1hr. As long as it is not expired you can use it..